# How to package a python module that imports another module within that package

Tags: python-3.x, import, pip, package, virtualenv

I am creating a python 3.7.2 package that I am then installing in different location, inside a virtualenv to use in an application. My package has multiple modules with dependencies (imports) between them. I can't figure out how to get the package to load correctly so that I can use the dependent modules in the package.

Package directory

```
root
\- foo # my package
   \- __init__.py # empty or with from .helper_class import HelperClass
   \- helper_class.py
   \- my_class.py # imports helper_class
   setup.py
```

Application directory

```
app
\- main.py # from foo.my_class import MyClass
\- venv
```

When `my_class` doesn't import `helper_class`, I can package, install and run `main.py` just fine. When I import `helper_class` in `my_class`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.my_class import MyClass
  File "/Users/XXXXXX/tmp/foo/my_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from helper_class import HelperClass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper_class'
```

I've tried an empty `__init__.py`, and also adding `from .helper_class import HelperClass` to `__init__.py`. I've added .s to the references all over the place, but no love.

There must be something extremely obvious that I'm missing.

app/main.py

```
o = MyClass()
print(o.get_att())
```

foo/my_class.py

```
from helper_class import HelperClass

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 123
    def get_att(self):
        return self.att
```

foo/helper_class.py

```
class HelperClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Setup.py below (taken from https://github.com/navdeep-G/setup.py)

```
    name=NAME,
    version=about['__version__'],
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    packages=['foo', ],
    # packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests", "*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*"]),
    # If your package is a single module, use this instead of 'packages':
    # py_modules=['mypackage'],

    # entry_points={
    #     'console_scripts': ['mycli=mymodule:cli'],
    # },
    install_requires=REQUIRED,
    extras_require=EXTRAS,
    include_package_data=True,
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        # Trove classifiers
        # Full list: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy'
    ],
    # $ setup.py publish support.
    # cmdclass={
    #     'upload': UploadCommand,
    # },
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to import it as below ...

```
from foo.helper_class import HelperClass
```

Comment: I think you can't upvote but you can accept it as.. mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Accepted. One wrinkle, I also added '__all__ = [(list of modules)]' to __init__.py. That may or may not have been part of the solution

Comment: Might be it is not.